# Grails/Hibernate - Criteria to fetch a master by two child records

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

For the domain classes below.

```
class Author {
    String name;
    static hasMany=[books:Book]
}

class Book {
    int serialNumber;
    String name;
}
```

I would like to get the Author whose,

1. first(serialNumber=1) book is "ABC"(name) AND
2. second(serialNumber=2) book is "XYZ"(name)

Even though there are data matching the condition, The below code doesn't work

```
def c = Author.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    books {
        and {
            and {
                eq("serialNumber", 1)
                eq("name", 'ABC')
            }
            and {
                eq("serialNumber", 2)
                eq("name", 'XYZ')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have only a basic knowledge of SQL, so if you are suggesting any SQL based solution, please guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid (not 100% sure) Criteria syntax can only query a single child record, so you'll have to use HQL like:

```
from Author as a
where exists (
  from Book as b1 where b1.author = a and b1.serialNumber = 1 and b1.name = 'ABC'
)
and exists (
  from Book as b2 where b2.author = a and b2.serialNumber = 2 and b1.name = 'XYZ'
)
```

Maybe you can replace `from Book as b2 where b2.author = a` with `from a.books as b2` - I cannot test it now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those and's are superfluous, since your code is equivalent to

```
def c = Author.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    books {
        eq("serialNumber", 1)
        eq("name", 'ABC')
        eq("serialNumber", 2)
        eq("name", 'XYZ')
    }
}
```

This is easier to understand and it means "find the Authors that own a book whose serial number is 1 and 2 at the same time and whose name is ABC and XYZ at the same time" and of course will not return anything.

I doubt your model allows for such queries using criteria, so I would advise to use HQL or other means.

Answer (score 0):

use "inList"

```
Collection<Author> authors = Author.createCriteria().list {
  books {
     inList('serialNumber', [1L, 2L])
     inList('name', ['A', 'B'])
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not verify that the Book with serialNumber 1 is named 'A', nor that the one with serialNumber 2 is 'B", nor that any of those combinations exists, i.e. it will return an Author if he has a book with serialNumber 2 and name 'A'.